# Quantization of radiation with canonical conjugate variables

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, hamiltonian, commutator, canonical-conjugation

I am reading the [Introduction to quantum optics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/introduction-to-quantum-optics/F45DCE785DC8226D4156EC15CAD5FA9A) book and I am a bit stuck at the quantization of electromagnetic field (around page 317).

The problem in this case is that we can't just express the electromagnetic field in terms of position and momentum, but we need other operators to express the field. This is why we look for canonical conjugate variables which could be used to express the fields.

The author argues that if we find pairs of quantities $Q_i$,$P_i$ which satisfy the Hamilton's equations
$$
\frac{d Q_i}{dt} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial P_i} \qquad \frac{d P_i}{dt} = - \frac{\partial H}{\partial Q_i}
$$
then these are canonical conjugate variables and can be used to quantize our field. For example with the hamiltonian for free radiation
$$
H_R = \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \int_V{d^3r [ \textbf{E}(\textbf{r},t)^2 + c^2 \textbf{B}(\textbf{r},t)^2]}
$$
and
$$
\alpha_l(t) = \frac{1}{2 C_l} \cdot (\omega_l A_l(t) -i E_l(t)) \qquad \textbf{E}(\textbf{r},t)= \sum_l{\textbf{e}_l E_l(t)}e^{i \cdot \textbf{k}_l \cdot \textbf{r}} \qquad \textbf{A}(\textbf{r},t)= \sum_l{\textbf{e}_l A_l(t)}e^{i \cdot \textbf{k}_l \cdot \textbf{r}}
$$

with $C_l$ being an arbitrary constant, we can find that the following quantities $Q_l$ and $P_l$ satisfy the Hamilton's equations :
$$
Q_l = \sqrt{\frac{4\epsilon_0 L^3}{\omega_l}} C_l \operatorname{Re} \{\alpha_l \} \qquad P_l = \sqrt{\frac{4\epsilon_0 L^3}{\omega_l}} C_l \operatorname{Im} \{\alpha_l \}
$$

Now come my questions :

1. How can I show that the poisson bracket of these two quantities $\{Q_l, P_l\} = 1$ (knowing that the two quantities satisfy Hamilton's equations) and hence the associated quantum operators satisfy the commutation relation $[\hat{Q_l},\hat{P_l}] = i \hbar$ ? (please be precise and do not skip steps during the evaluation of the poisson brackets)
2. This is a more general question: So do these canonical conjugate operators have a deeper physical meaning or are they just here to help us express "real" quantities like electric and magnetic field?

EDIT: I am not sure if this is useful but the time dependence of $\alpha_l$ can be found to be $\alpha_l(t) = \alpha_l(0) e^{-i \omega_l t}$.

Comment: Please don't use fracture, it's unreadable.

Comment: It is not clear for me what you mean with fracture. What should I change in my post?

Comment: I think this is in reference to the oddly scripted letters used in your question.

Comment: Stuff like $\Re\{\alpha_l \}$. $\text{Re}(\alpha_l)$ looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are working in Coulomb gauge so that

$$
\mathbf{E}=-\mathbf{\dot{A}},\quad\mathbf{B}=\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{A}
$$

In this case:
$$
\mathbf{E}\left(\mathbf{r},\,t\right)=\sum_{\mathbf{k},\lambda} \mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{k},\lambda} E_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\left(t\right)\exp\left(i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}\right)=-\sum_{\mathbf{k},\lambda} \mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{k},\lambda} \dot{A}_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\left(t\right)\exp\left(i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}\right)
$$

So that $E_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}=-\dot{A}_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}$. Note that I switched to using the wavevector as a label, and summing over polarization separately ($\lambda$). Next, it is convenient to write the Hamiltonian in terms of these quantities. So:

$$
\begin{align}
\int_V d^3 r E^2&=\sum_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\sum_{\mathbf{k}',\lambda'}\mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\cdot\mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{k}',\lambda'}E_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}E_{\mathbf{k}',\lambda'}.\int_V d^3 r \exp\left(i\left[\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{k}'\right]\cdot\mathbf{r}\right)\\
&=\mathcal{V}.\sum_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\sum_{\mathbf{k}',\lambda'}\mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\cdot\mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{k}',\lambda'}E_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}E_{\mathbf{k}',\lambda'}\delta_{\mathbf{k},-\mathbf{k}'}\\
&=\mathcal{V}.\sum_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}E_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}E_{-\mathbf{k},\lambda}
\end{align}
$$

Where I introduced a finite volume for integration $V$, which then led to volume-units constant $\mathcal{V}$. If you are looking at infinite volume, then you would probably need to use integrals to express your fields - not series over $\mathbf{k}$. I also assumed $\mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\cdot\mathbf{e}_{-\mathbf{k},\lambda'}=\delta_{\lambda,\lambda'}$ which should be fairly uncontroversial, these are there simply for polarization control, and we are saying that we will use same polarization basis for counter-propagating waves, and that polarization vectors are orthogonal for different $\lambda$. Therefore:

$$
\begin{align}
\int_V d^3 r E^2&=\mathcal{V}.\sum_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}E_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}E_{-\mathbf{k},\lambda}\\
&=\mathcal{V}.\sum_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\dot{A}_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\dot{A}_{-\mathbf{k},\lambda}
\end{align}
$$

For magnetic field you have, it is convenient to do some simplification using the Coulomb Gauge, i.e. $\boldsymbol{\nabla}.\mathbf{A}=0$

$$
\begin{align}
\int_V d^3 r B^2 &= \int_V d^3r \left(\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{A}\right)\cdot \left(\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{A}\right)\\
&=-\int_V d^3r \boldsymbol{\nabla}.\left[\mathbf{A}\times \left(\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{A}\right)\right]-\int_V d^3r \mathbf{A}\cdot \nabla^2\mathbf{A}+\int_V d^3r \left[\mathbf{A}.\boldsymbol{\nabla}\right]\cdot \left[\boldsymbol{\nabla}.\mathbf{A}\right]
\end{align}
$$

The last term vanishes due to Coulomb gauge, the first term can be converted into surface integral, and one conventionally assumes that volume $V$ is large enough for field to vanish outside it. Other treatments are possible as well, of course. With this:

$$
\begin{align}
\int_V d^3 r B^2 &= -\int_V d^3r \mathbf{A}\cdot \nabla^2\mathbf{A}\\
&=-\sum_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\sum_{\mathbf{k}',\lambda'}\mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\cdot\mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{k}',\lambda'}A_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}A_{\mathbf{k}',\lambda'}.\left(-\mathbf{k}'.\mathbf{k}'\right)\int_V d^3 r \exp\left(i\left[\mathbf{k}+\mathbf{k}'\right]\cdot\mathbf{r}\right)\\
&=\mathcal{V}.\sum_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}k^2 A_{\mathbf{k},\lambda} A_{-\mathbf{k},\lambda}
\end{align}
$$

Thus the Hamiltonian is:

$$
\begin{align}
H&=\frac{\mathcal{V}\epsilon_0}{2}\sum_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\left[\left|\dot{A}_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\right|^2+c^2k^2 \left|A_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\right|^2\right]=\frac{\mathcal{V}\epsilon_0}{2}\sum_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\left[\left|\dot{A}_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\right|^2+\omega^2_{\mathbf{k}} \left|A_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\right|^2\right]\\
&=\frac{\mathcal{V}\epsilon_0}{2}\sum_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\left[\dot{A}_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\dot{A}_{-\mathbf{k},\lambda}+\omega^2_{\mathbf{k}} A_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}A_{-\mathbf{k},\lambda}\right]
\end{align}
$$

Where $|\dots|^2$ follows from $A_{-\mathbf{k},\lambda}=A_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}^\dagger$ in order to keep the fields real-valued. One can also derive the Lagrangian in much the same way:

$$
L=-\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int_V d^3 r \left[E^2-c^2B^2\right]=-\frac{\mathcal{V}\epsilon_0}{2}\sum_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\left[\dot{A}_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\dot{A}_{-\mathbf{k},\lambda}-\omega^2_{\mathbf{k}} A_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}A_{-\mathbf{k},\lambda}\right]
$$

From Lagrangian mechanics we then have

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\partial_{\dot{A}_{-\mathbf{k},\lambda}}L\right)&=\partial_{A_{-\mathbf{k},\lambda}}L \\
\ddot{A}_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}&=-\omega^2_{\mathbf{k}}A_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}
\end{align}
$$

So $A_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\left(t\right)=\exp\left(i\omega_{\mathbf{k}}t\right)A_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\left(0\right)$. Where the choice of sign in the exponent is arbitrary, but we need to have $\omega_{-\mathbf{k}}=-\omega_{\mathbf{k}}$ for complex conjugates to work the right way.

With this, $\dot{A}_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}=i\omega_{\mathbf{k}} A_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}$, so:

$$
\begin{align}
H&=\mathcal{V}\epsilon_0 \sum_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\omega^2_{\mathbf{k}} A_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}A_{-\mathbf{k},\lambda}
\end{align}
$$

Which is reasonable, we are simply summing the energy in the independent modes.

Next, let me define:

$$
\begin{align}
Q_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}&=\alpha_{\mathbf{k}}\cdot\left(A_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}+A_{-\mathbf{k},\lambda}\right)\\
P_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}&=i\omega_{\mathbf{k}}\alpha_{\mathbf{k}}\cdot\left(A_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}-A_{-\mathbf{k},\lambda}\right)
\end{align}
$$

One can show that:

$$
\begin{align}
H&=\frac{\mathcal{V}\epsilon_0}{2} \sum_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\frac{\alpha_{\mathbf{k}}^2}{\omega_{\mathbf{k}}^2}\left[\frac{P^2_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}}{2}+\omega^2_{\mathbf{k}}\frac{Q^2_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}}{2}\right]
\end{align}
$$

One can now readily check that:

$$
\partial_{P_{\mathbf{k}\lambda}}H=\frac{\mathcal{V}\epsilon_0\alpha_{\mathbf{k}}^2}{2} \cdot\frac{1}{\omega_{\mathbf{k}}^2}\cdot P_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}=\dot{Q}_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}
$$

if $\alpha_{\mathbf{k}}=\sqrt{2\omega_{\mathbf{k}}^2/\mathcal{V}\epsilon_0}$

And

$$
\partial_{Q_{\mathbf{k}\lambda}}H=\frac{\mathcal{V}\epsilon_0\alpha_{\mathbf{k}}^2}{2} \cdot\frac{1}{\omega_{\mathbf{k}}^2}\cdot \omega_{\mathbf{k}}^2 Q_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}=\omega_{\mathbf{k}}^2 Q_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}=-\dot{P}_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}
$$

To evaluate the [Poisson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket), all you need to do is to evaluate derivatives with respect to $P$ whilst keeping $Q$ fixed, and the other way round. If you like, by definition

$$
\begin{align}
\partial_{P_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}}P_{\mathbf{k}',\lambda'}&=\delta_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k}'}\delta_{\lambda,\lambda'} \\
\partial_{P_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}}Q_{\mathbf{k}',\lambda'}&=0
\end{align}
$$

And the other way round. So:

$$
\begin{align}
\{Q_{\mathbf{k},\lambda},\,P_{\mathbf{k}',\lambda'}\}&=\sum_{\mathbf{k}'',\lambda''}\left[\partial_{Q_{\mathbf{k}'',\lambda''}}Q_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\partial_{P_{\mathbf{k}'',\lambda''}}P_{\mathbf{k}',\lambda'}-\partial_{P_{\mathbf{k}'',\lambda''}}Q_{\mathbf{k},\lambda}\partial_{Q_{\mathbf{k}'',\lambda''}}P_{\mathbf{k}',\lambda'}\right]\\
&=\sum_{\mathbf{k}'',\lambda''}\left[\delta_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k}''}\delta_{\lambda,\lambda''}\delta_{\mathbf{k}',\mathbf{k}''}\delta_{\lambda',\lambda''}-0\right]=\\
&=\left(\sum_{\mathbf{k}''}\delta_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k}''}\delta_{\mathbf{k},'\mathbf{k}''}\right)\left(\sum_{\lambda''}\delta_{\lambda,\lambda''}\delta_{\lambda',\lambda''}\right)=\\
&=\delta_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k}'}\delta_{\lambda,\lambda'}
\end{align}
$$

---

Do the conjugate operators have physical meaning? [Ballentine](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Quantum-Mechanics-Development-Leslie-Ballentine/dp/9810241054) has a nice approach where expressions for momentum operator are derived as consequences of symmetries (invariance with respect to translation). Hamiltonian itself is then a quantity that is conserved as a result of invariance with respect to temporal shifts. I would try to seek significance there. But I am not ready to give a simple answer. i.e. the things that are significant are those that characterize motion, i.e. remain constant during motion, and these happen to be related to Lagrangian and Hamiltonian via derivatives.

Comment: I didn't ask to redefine the whole problem. I already defined all the needed quantities. The question 1. in my post only asks to explain the evaluation of the poisson bracket of $Q_l$ and $P_l$, which you actually skipped in your post.

Comment: @NicolasSchmid, from your definitions it was not clear whether the quantities do satisfy the Hamiltonian equations, your conflation of labeling of the wavevector and polarization made it unclear what the relations between complex conjugation and wavevector inversion are. This is important since real and imaginary parts of $A$ are essentially treated as independent. Too shaky for my liking, so I fixed it. As far as the Poisson bracket is concerned, all you really needed to do is to take the definitions in terms of partial derivatives and evaluate them. Anyway, I added it to the reply above